# Increase Mac Mail App Font

Tags: mail.app, font

Is there any way to increase the size of the font that is used in the navigation pane in Mac Mail?  For example, where it lists Inbox, Sent, Junk, etc?  I am not referring to the message list or the messages themselves, I already know those can be changes in Mail Preferences.

This is what I am referring to:

[image]

I downloaded TinkerTool but have failed to get that to change the Mail fonts.

Comment: did you consider using the "Zoom" feature

Comment: Zoom in Mail is a stupidly named feature that does not zoom anything.  All it does is change the window size to fill the screen.  Nothing gets zoomed.  This is just one of many reasons I think Mac Mail is the worst mail client ever.  I don't use it personally, I am trying to figure this out for my boss.

Comment: OK, I was talking about the Zoom function in the Accessibility in System Preferences. Turn it on and try.

Comment: Interesting. I have never played with Accessibilty's Zoom feature before.  Thanks for the idea but it is not what I am looking for.  I simply want to increase the size of the fonts in Mac Mail's left-most nav pane without zooming the netire screen, and without having to have a picture in picture zoom follow the curser around.